# Can Windows games run well in VMWare Fusion 12?

Tags: vmware-fusion, 3d-graphics

I'm trying to play Steam games in VMWare Fusion 12 player, on MacOS 11.6, from Bootcamp partition with Windows 10. I'm having problems, and wondering if there are options to improve the experience.

I get an error window appearing often when I run Elder Scrolls: Oblivion. But Oblivion otherwise runs, as it did in Fusion 10. (I used to get this error in Fusion 10, too.)

[image: Error from Windows about OpenGL driver]

I tried to run Dishonored, but it freezes. Title graphics play but the start screen with 3D content stalls, even the audio doesn't work.

My guess is that games are not going to work, and that the 3D support is primarily intended for running 3D authoring tools. But maybe someone else has had better luck.

Of course I can simply boot into Windows, but can't help but be curious about this. 3D obviously works sometimes. They claim to support up to OpenGL 4.1 and DirectX 11, so I thought old games would all run smoothly. So is it my setup, or is this normal?

Comment: In order to the applications, you are attempting to run within a VM you would need VT-d (or AMD's equivalent), the error you have provided is indicating that the VM in question does not support OpenGL. You would also have to install the drivers for the GPU within the VM itself.

Comment: Did you install the guest additions into your VM?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas do you mean "VMWare Tools"? If so, yes. Otherwise, I don't know what you mean by "guest additions".

Comment: @Ramhound the VM is a Bootcamp partition. All drivers are provided by Apple when setting up Bootcamp. There are no OEM drivers available for Windows on Apple hardware. Also, there are no Macs with AMD CPUs.

Comment: @BoredAstronaut - Bootcamp isn't a VM, what connection to Bootcamp is there to a VMWare Fusion a hypervisor?

Comment: @Ramhound the connection is that they're using the same Windows 10 installation on the same disk partition. But the point is that all drivers come from Apple, and there are no additional drivers that I can install. You said I "have to install the drivers for the GPU" but I cannot do that. VMWare installs its own driver, also. There is nothing from VMWare that I can install.

Comment: @BoredAstronaut - I am still confused by the fact you referred to a VM through VMWare Fusion in your question but in a comment suggested you were using Bootcamp.

Comment: @Ramhound VMWare Fusion can use the Bootcamp partition as a VM. I admit, I don't know exactly how they make it work smoothly, but it does—except maybe in this case. Windows does not complain whether you boot directly or through VMWare. Perhaps a pure VM on a disk image would work more reliably for accelerated 3D.

Comment: @BoredAstronaut - Your question really should clarify that fact.  But I don't believe it's the reason you are unable to run a DX11 or OpenGL application within the VM.